# Configure PHP on IIS with FastCGI to show warnings but continue executiuon

Tags: php, php-7

I am using PHP (7.3.7) Non-ThreadSafe on IIS (windows) as FastCGI.

PHP installation is fresh and just `php.ini-development` renamed to `php.ini` thus `error_reporting` is set to `E_ALL`

running following script

```
<?php
echo "some text\n" ;
echo $aaaaaaa;
echo "another text\n" ;
?>
```

will generate output

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: aaaaaaa in ****\article.php on line 3
```

Note that first and 3rd lines are missing from output.

Using same installation of php, on apache (2.4.39) and nginx (1.17.2) (also on windows system) shows following output

```
some text
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: aaaaaaa in ****\article.php on line 3
another text
```

**Is there an specific configuration that I need to change so PHP show same output as apache, nginx in IIS too?**
or in other words, how can I configure my setup to show warning and notices and also the output of script.

I tried same script with PHP (7.1.30, 7.2.11, 5.2.10.10) and same issue still persists on IIS but not on apache or nginx.

**Edit**

- I know that if I set `error_reporting` is set to `E_ALL`, all errors, warning and notices are shown and when I change it to `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED` notices and warnings are disabled and won't show.
- I also know that $aaaaaaa is not defined and it being there is for illustration of the issue.

**Edit 2**
It seems this has to do with configuration of fast-cgi on IIS. On same machine with same php installation and configuration using `apache` and `nginx` I can see exactly what Phil and sancoLgates shown in their links. I am editing my question to reflect the issue

Comment: Cannot reproduce your observations ~ https://3v4l.org/coFKX

Comment: its working exactly like you want in my machine

Comment: Strange! https://imgur.com/r1rUkaD, php instalation is a new copy, I just uncommented some extensions that I need.

Comment: Is that literally all the code that `test.php` contains?

Comment: Yes, https://imgur.com/UpvNERM and if helps, I'm running on windows and PHP 7.2.11

Comment: Try `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE & ~ E_DEPRECATED & ~ E_STRICT & ~ E_USER_NOTICE & ~ E_USER_DEPRECATED);`

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/IpIg9P2.png

Comment: @sancoLgates, what is version of your PHP and which OS?

Comment: @Gulshan, that would disable the notice, isn't it? I want to see notice and also rest of the script output just the way Phil and Sanco shown in their output

Comment: Don't write code ignoring error ! It look like ***you are writing php error garbage system*** .....

Comment: @hs-dev2MR I don't understand what do you mean. the code in my question is to illustrate issue, which is important to me to fix my problem. Obviously I don't want to show notices in my production code, but in development I need to see the warnings **and** render of the page together.

Comment: It is not possible to continue execution when error occur ! You dont want to show notice in production , so turn on error report and fix that when occur will be more better for local and production

Comment: @hs-dev2MR it is not an error, it is notice, and even if error occurs it should show the page content before error, which is the case in apache and nginx

Answer (score -1):

In your code variable `$aaaaaaa` is not defined so define it first. 
To check error add this code

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);

    // and then add your code below 

    ?>
```

Comment: Seems you didn't read the question, or the other answer which is not correct. I intentionally didn't define the variable to cause the notice appear!